# How to get the label string as formControl value in dropdown angular2?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular2-forms

here is what i trying to achieve, i want to get the label string as my formControl value, but i need selected changed event too which is i need the value when it changed, here is my code :

HTML :

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedListKota" #t (change)="ZonaChanged(t.value)" formControlName="nama_zona">
                                <option *ngFor="let lz of listKota" [value]="lz.value">  
                                {{lz.label}}
                                </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Here is my app.component.ts :

```
      constructor(private frmInputMasterBassService: FrmInputMasterBassService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

        this.sStorage = sessionStorage.getItem('mAuth');
        this.sStorage = JSON.parse(this.sStorage);

        this.frmInputMasterBassService.getKotaList().subscribe(
          data => {
            this.data = data.json();
            for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
                this.listKota.push({label:this.data[i].KOTA, value:this.data[i].PROVINSI});
            }

            this.selectedListKota = this.listKota[0].value;
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
              }
          }
        );

        this.form= this.formBuilder.group({
          nama_bass: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
          alamat_bass: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
          nomor_telepon: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
          nama_zona: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
          contact_person: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
          email: ['', Validators.nullValidator]
        })

      }

  ZonaChanged(value){
    console.log(value);
    this.zona = value;
  }
```

here is my listKota array JSON looked like :

```
  [{
    "label": "AGAM",
    "value": "Sumatera Barat"
  },
  {
    "label": "AIR MOLEK",
    "value": "Riau"
  }]
```

when i want to choose AGAM, my form JSON will be looked like this :

```
{
  "nama_bass": "",
  "alamat_bass": "",
  "nomor_telepon": "",
  "nama_zona": "Sumatera Barat",
  "contact_person": "",
  "email": ""
}
```

the "nama_zona" i want is point to AGAM, not "Sumatera Barat" how can i changed this without change value when event (changed) triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution I can think of: I would probably set `[value]="lz.label"` in the form, so that you will get the desired value in your form.

Then in the change event you'd pass the label and find the object in your array which has the same label.

By the way, no need to use ngModel here, if you don't need it for something else. So here's what I suggest for you:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <select class="form-control" #t (change)="ZonaChanged(t.value)" formControlName="nama_zona">
    <option *ngFor="let lz of listKota" [value]="lz.label">  
      {{lz.label}}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>
```

and the `ZonaChanged`-method:

```
ZonaChanged(label){
  this.zona = this.listKota.find(x => x.label == label)
  // this.zona = this.zona.value;
}
```

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/oM9PUCDrEJJAlPLKUTP3?p=preview)

Now in `zona` you have the complete object, which you can work with.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)